# Show tags out of the loop

Tags: php, html, loops

Well I have a script that was just tab contains header information when clicked down that appears.
I put it into my code comes first, the group was shown as well as the subGroup ...

I see the code
Including ul tag that is located outside the loop
and also Including li and a tag that is located inside the loop
So far Right.
But I have `<div></div>` tag which must be put out of `<ul>` tags that subgroup Show but can not?

```
<div id="horizontalTab" class="col-md-12">
  <?php
$sql="select * from category";
$stmt=$db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
echo '<ul>';
while($result=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $id=$result['id'];
    $name=$result['name'];

$sql2="select * from sub where catid='".$id."' ";
$stmt2=$db->prepare($sql2);
$stmt2->execute();
$num=$stmt2->rowCount();

echo '<li><a href="#'.$id.'"> '.$name.'</a></li>';
echo '<div id="'.$id.'">';

while($result2=$stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

$id2=$result2['id'];
$name2=$result2['name'];
echo ''.$name2.'';
}
}
echo '</div>';
echo '</ul>';
?>
</div>
```

Also html my code

```
<div id="horizontalTab" class="col-md-12">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tab-1">shop</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-2">shop1</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tab-1">
    info shop1
  </div>
  <div id="tab-2">
    info shop2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so much for prepared statements `catid='".$id."' ";`

Comment: https://xkcd.com/327/